# Which layers in a neural network use activation functions?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Does the input layer of a neural network use activation functions, or is it just the hidden and output layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidden and output layer neurons possess activation functions, but input layer neurons do not, input layer just gets input and multiply it with unique weights. Activation functions perform a transformation on the input received.

Comment: And just to clarify, by weight, you mean the weight between the input neuron, and the first hidden layer's neuron? Not a weight between the input neuron and the physical input?

Comment: Yes exactly, weight refers to the strength or amplitude of a connection between two nodes. The two nodes can be of any two consecutive layers.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a figure of a 3-layer neural network from Stanford's class on NN for visual recognition.

[image]

The two hidden layers will always have an activation function. The output layer may or may not have an activation function: for binary classification, you might have a sigmoid function to squash your output, but for regression, you typically will not have an activation function.

For clarity, the hidden layers compute:

```
output = activation_function(W x inputs + b)
```

As you probably know, the `activation_function()` may be a `sigmoid`, `tanh`, `ReLU`, or other.

Comment: Okay, so even the output layer is questionable, sweet, thank you!